# MIME subject decoding, when RFC are not respected

Tags: mime, decoding

Subject mime field is in ASCII. Every character excluded by the ASCII table has to be Q/encoded or base64/encoded. Content-Type field in the header has also nothing to do with the way subject is encoded. Am I correct?

However (and unfortunately) some clients (read Microsoft Outlook 6 for example) insert a string encoded in whatever (BIG5 for example) in the header, without specifying with q/base64 encoding that the string is in BIG5. How can i handle these wrongly-encoded emails? Is there a standard way, to parse these?

My goal is to have the biggest compatibility possible, even by using 3rd part paid programs; how can i do that? *(sorry for my buggy english)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subject header encoding has nothing to do with Content-Type header. There is no "perfect" way to handle Subject. I've implemented this just by a hack that tries to see if all characters of text fit in big5, if not then try next encoding in order.

Big5, utf-8, latin-1, q/base64 and finally ascii

Comment: this is interesting. there is no way that latin-1 fits in big5 (for example), right? Thanks

Comment: It has been long since I did that, so can't remember for sure. But you may find this useful to get started: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/DetectEncoding.aspx